# "GET /new_entry/5 HTTP/1.1" 200 466

Tags: django

When I am learning Django, 
The console usually hint me:

```
"GET /new_entry/5 HTTP/1.1" 200 466
```

What's the purpose of 200 466?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `200` is the [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success), which means the request completed successfully. The second number is the size of the request in bytes.